# How to declare in Django Models a class with an attribute pointing to the same class?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I declare the previous or next attributes pointing to the same class type ?

I couln't find the answer in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/)

In the models.py below I have just written "scenes" for **previous** and **next**

```
from pickle import TRUE
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event name', max_length=120)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    previous = models.ForeignKey(scenes, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    next = models.ForeignKey(scenes, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'self'` to refer to the same model. But here you likely can work with a [**`OneToOneField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) with `next` as value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the `previous` field. That way when you set *B* as the `next` of *A*, *A* is the `previous` of *B* automatically:

```
from pickle import TRUE
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event name', max_length=120)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    previous = models.OneToOneField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='next'
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).